# is it possible to find overlapping matches with a single regex?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Here's a sample which executes the `preg_replace` multiple times to find nested/overlapping matches:

```
$text = '[foo][foo][/foo][/foo]';
//1st:   ^^^^^     ^^^^^^
//2nd:        ^^^^^      ^^^^^^
//3rd: fails

do {
    $text = preg_replace('~\[foo](.*?)\[/foo]~', '[bar]$1[/bar]', $text, -1, $replace_count);
} while ($replace_count);

echo $text; //'[bar][bar][/bar][/bar]'
```

I'm satisfied with the result the and behavior. However, it seems inefficient to scan through the whole string 3 times as in the example above. Is there any regex magic to do this in a single replace?

Conditions:

- I can't simply replace `~\[(/)?foo]~` with `[$1bar]`, I need to make sure there is a matching closing `[/foo]` tag after an opening `[foo]` tag and replace them both at a time. It doesn't matter whether they're nested or not. Unpaired `[foo]` and `[/foo]` should **not** be replaced.

In JS I could set the Regex object's `lastIndex` property to the beginning of the match so that it starts matching again from the beginning of the last match. I couldn't find any `startIndex` option for regex replacing in PHP, and working with `substr()`ing could also be inefficient. I've looked around whether PCRE would have an achor for "start next match at this position" or similar but I had no luck.

Is there a better approach?

---

To clarify on unpaired tags, given the input:

```
[foo][foo][/foo]
```

I'm fine with either `[bar][foo][/bar]` or `[foo][bar][/bar]` as output. The former is the legacy behavior.

Comment: With my experience I would say it's impossible. But I would be quite happy to see someone dazzle me ! In the mean time, here's a more [sophisticated regex](http://regex101.com/r/xY0fT2) that matches the appropriate nested tags !

Comment: First at all, your code doesn't work as you think, try it with the string `[foo][foo][/foo]`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I believe it works. The unpaired `[foo]` in the middle won't be replaced, right? That's what I expect to happen actually. Oh I wasn't very clear on the "pairing" part, the first open tag with the first close tag that follows it is a fine pairing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full regex solution is not possible for this specific case.

Your solution adapted to match paired tags (in the common sense):

```
$pattern = '~\[foo]((?>[^[]++|\[(?!/?foo]))*)\[/foo]~';
$result = $text;
do {
    $result = preg_replace($pattern, '[bar]$1[/bar]', $result, -1, $count);
} while ($count);
```

Another way that parses the string only once:

```
$arr = preg_split('~(\[/?foo])~', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$stack = array();
foreach ($arr as $key=>$item) {
    if ($item == '[foo]') $stack[] = $key;
    else if ($item == '[/foo]' && !empty($stack)) {
        $arr[array_pop($stack)] = '[bar]';
        $arr[$key] = '[/bar]'; 
    }
}
$result = implode($arr);
```

the performance of this second script is independant of the depth.

To answer the title question, yes it is possible to find overlapping matches with a single regex, however, you can't perform a replacement with this kind of pattern, example:

```
$pattern = '~(?=(\[foo]((?>[^[]++|\[(?!/?foo)|(?1))*)\[/foo]))~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
```

The trick is to use a lookahead and a capturing group. Note that the whole match is always an empty string, this is the reason why you can't use this pattern with preg_replace.

Comment: +1 thanks for the excellent options. I'll analyze them a bit and report back.

Comment: I see you've edited the answer removing the recursion, as it is unnecessary in my case. So, is `(?>[^[]++|\[(?!/?foo]))*` just a faster alternative for `.*?`?

Comment: I can see that you're using a possessive quantifier and once-only subpattern to avoid backtracking, but would `.*?` do any backtracking?

Comment: The lazy quantifier `.*?` must check at each position if the following subpattern matches the string. If you use a greedy quantifier, the regex engine doesn't have to make these checks and matches all that is possible (and goes back until the following subpattern matches). But since I use a negated character class, the group can only match until an other tag (closing or opening). Since I use a possessive quantifier and an atomic group, the pattern will fail faster if the closing tag is not found.

Comment: `.*?` doesn't ensure that there is no other tags between two tags.

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't see that `/?` in the lookahead. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is to find the end `[/foo]` and backtrack until you find a begin `[foo]` or `[foo(space).*]`. Replace match region with something else and keep doing it until no ending is found. But with regular `strpos/stripos` or plain old `substr`, not `regex`.

It might be achievable with `regex`, but I've always done this kind of thing with regular seeks as it's also faster.

Comment: I don't understand the nature of this answer. Remember, the ultimate goal is to do this in one single regex (without loops).

Comment: @HamZa He asks `Is there a better approach?`. You noticed it... right? Right at the end.

Comment: `Is there any regex magic to do this in a single replace?` Noticed ?

Comment: @HamZa There isn't *(afaik)*, so I gave him a faster solution. Cool, right?

Comment: I actually have an alternative using `strpos` and `substr_replace`, though I'd like to see if it is possible with Regex before I go back to `substr_replace`'ing.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I've personally never gone into `voodoo regex`. So it may be doable. But when something is too awesome for a simple regex, it's always faster/easier to implement by hand. I don't care if this answer gets voted or selected. I wanted to post a solution here so you/others don't waste time if no proper answer appears.

Comment: Thanks. `=]` The problem with `strpos`, `strrpos` backtracking and `substr_replace` is that it grows unmaintainable quite fast, at least when I code them (though the same can be said about regex). This seemed like a simpler task for regex, but I may settle with string methods if this can't be done with regex.